# Using JetBrains Rider, is there a way to see elapsed time when debugging?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

In Visual Studio, you get this when you step over a line while debugging:

[image]

I can't seem to find an equivalent in Rider. Is there something like it?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @Jogge I found somewhere else confirmation that these feature isn't in Rider yet.

Comment: Found the feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-5116

Comment: 2 years and 7 months later and still the same state...

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments to my original question, this feature still hasn't been implemented yet

As a workaround, if I *really* need to know the elapsed time, I've just been using a stop watch.

Example:

```cs
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
// Code you care about goes here
sw.Stop();
// Put breakpoint here, then use debugger to look at sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, JetBrains team implemented this feature. U can check release 2024.1 EAP 3 update https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2024/02/02/rider-2024-1-eap-3/#debugger